# how to fetch database using session value

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-signin

i am trying to build gmail login based website by using this code..

```
require_once"GoogleAPI/vendor/autoload.php";
    $gClient =  new Google_Client();
    $gClient->setClientId("687256925109-l9ea7sns693uiapmgppprdupmigllf00.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    $gClient->setClientSecret("8NqZqdj22fd_Ool6orj7wOeF");
    $gClient->setApplicationName("Trade2trade Login");
    $gClient->setRedirectUri("http://localhost/trade2trade/log_in.php");
    $gClient->addScope("email profile");


    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    } else{
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        $token = $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
        $outh = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
        $userData = $outh->userinfo_v2_me->get();
        $_SESSION['mail_user_email'] = $userData['email'];
        header("Location: log_in.php");
        }
    }
```

once it will fetch from gmail i am saving mail in `$_SESSION`.
in login process i am giving first preference it will login with input items,

```
<form method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input name="user_email" type="email" class="form-control-user form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input name="user_password" class="form-control-user form-control" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" name="login">
                      Login
                    </button>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $login_url; ?>'"class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                      <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Login with Google
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Login with Facebook
                    </a>
                  </form>
```

in second my i am try to use that saved $_SESSION['mail_user_email'] try to fetch data, it was not working.

/// Login With input Items

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

          $user_email = clean_text(strtolower($_POST['user_email']));
          $user_password = clean_text($_POST['user_password']);

          if(empty($user_email && $user_password)){

            echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>Please Check in All Fields</div>";

          } else{

            $query_login_process = "SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE user_email = '{$user_email}' ";
            $result_login_process = mysqli_query($connection, $query_login_process);

            if(!$result_login_process){

              die("Error while fetching login Details from database" . mysqli_error($connection));

            } else {

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_login_process)) {

                     $db_user_name = $row['user_name'];
                     $db_user_first_name = $row['user_firstname'];
                     $db_user_last_name = $row['user_lastname'];
                     $db_user_email = $row['user_email'];
                     $db_user_password = $row['user_password'];
                     $db_user_content = $row['user_content'];
                     $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
              }
              if($db_user_role === "Admin"){
                  if($user_email === $db_user_email && $user_password === $db_user_password){

                       $_SESSION['user_name'] = $db_user_name;
                       $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_first_name;
                       $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $db_user_last_name;
                       $_SESSION['user_email'] = $db_user_email;
                       $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;
                       header("Location: admin/");

                }
              } else if ($db_user_role === "Subscriber"){
                      if($user_email === $db_user_email && $user_password === $db_user_password){

                       $_SESSION['user_name'] = $db_user_name;
                       $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_first_name;
                       $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $db_user_last_name;
                       $_SESSION['user_email'] = $db_user_email;
                       $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;
                       header("Location: index.php");

                }
              } else {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid User name or password</div>";
              }
            }

              }

          } else if(isset($_SESSION['mail_user_email'])){   /// Login with gmail based
    echo $mail_user_email = $_SESSION['mail_user_email'];
    $query_login_process = "SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE user_email = '{$mail_user_email}' ";
    $result_login_process = mysqli_query($connection, $query_login_process);

    if(!$result_login_process){

      die("Error while fetching login Details from database" . mysqli_error($connection));

    } else {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_login_process)) {

             $db_user_name = $row['user_name'];
             $db_user_first_name = $row['user_firstname'];
             $db_user_last_name = $row['user_lastname'];
             $db_user_email = $row['user_email'];
             $db_user_password = $row['user_password'];
             $db_user_content = $row['user_content'];
             $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
      }
      if($db_user_role === "Admin"){
          if($user_email === $db_user_email && $user_password === $db_user_password){

               $_SESSION['user_name'] = $db_user_name;
               $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_first_name;
               $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $db_user_last_name;
               $_SESSION['user_email'] = $db_user_email;
               $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;
               header("Location: admin/");

        }
      } else if ($db_user_role === "Subscriber"){
              if($user_email === $db_user_email && $user_password === $db_user_password){

               $_SESSION['user_name'] = $db_user_name;
               $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_first_name;
               $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $db_user_last_name;
               $_SESSION['user_email'] = $db_user_email;
               $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;
               header("Location: index.php");

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

what i am missing please let me know..

Comment: Do not use functions like `clean_text`. Most likely it will damage your data at some point

Comment: thanks for those tips bro, ill use it for my code security and its improvement purpose.

Comment: Have you corrected the code, do you have more  information after these comments? Can you explain more what is the issue?

Comment: @Kessy i just created a gmail login with php, after i am getting email i am saving into session, with that session i am try to fetch it from database and if any mail registered with it, if there is no mail it has to display a msg like your mail not registered with us. this is what i want, after login gmail it was successfully fetching mail but it was fetch any data from database.

Comment: Maybe the error is comming from the database.